# Java array vs ArrayList vs List

Tags: java, arrays

Im trying to understand the relationship between array, ArrayList, and List.

Say I wanted to remove duplicates by converting an *array* into an *ArrayList* then into a *HashSet*, then returned to an *array*.

```
int[] start = {1,2,3,4,5};
....
....
....
int[] result = .....
```

How would that work?

Comment: If the goal is to remove duplicates, you do not need to make an ArrayList or a HashSet, but if you are just trying to experiment with conversion I believe there are methods in  
 `java.util`

Answer (score 1):

```
    int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    for(int i : array) {
        System.out.print(i+", ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    ArrayList myArrayList = new ArrayList();
    for(int num : array) {
        myArrayList.add(num);
    }
    System.out.println(myArrayList);
    HashSet<Integer> myHashSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for(int i = 0;i<myArrayList.size();i++) {
        myHashSet.add((Integer) myArrayList.get(i));
        
    }
    System.out.println(myHashSet);
```

This is an example of a normal int array converted to an ArrayList converted to a HashSet.

Answer (score 1):

Array is a fixed length data structure. It is a continuous block of memory. Let say you have an array at x3000 with a length of 2. An array stay at x3000 and x3001. Remember, this is oversimplifying the concept, as element size and size per memory location will certainly affect the position of array's elements (not always end at x3001).

List is an abstract data type (ADT), the notable difference between **list** and **array** is list has no fixed length. There can be more differences but it may vary from case to case.

ArrayList is a ADT list, but implemented using array. It's like when you do problems that require constructing stack, queue, etc using array.

Answer (score -1):

> the relationship between array, ArrayList, and List.

An array is created with the `[]` and `{}` notation you showed in your question. It's not dynamically allocated.

A List is an interface, which is just a guide to what methods its implementations must respond to.

An ArrayList is an implementation of a List.